# Can we fix linkage on election page to meta?

Tags: support, status-completed, election

It seems that the link for the questions on meta is not working. The link to Meta is noted as https://history.meta.com/tags/election but this should be https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/election

Can this be fixed? It's just a nitpick since I can find my way around this but it might not be so easy for others. [**Page in question**](https://history.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=election)

I have expertly drawn which link is broken ;)

[image]

Comment: One of the current moderators can do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. Thanks for reporting it!